# C: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c

Hello i've spent the last couple hours looking through this code attemting to find what is causing this memory error. Ive been told repeatedly that it is a situation of freeing something which was never malloced or freeing something twice, but I have gone through and shrunk the code down to make sure that neither of these is possible. The whole project is a linked list, but ive taken out most of the components of the project to make the smallest possible replication of the error. THanks!
The Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

struct lnode{
  int count;
  int line;
  struct lnode *next;
  char *word;
}; 

struct lnode* newNode (char* word, int line) {
  struct lnode *myNode = malloc(sizeof(struct  lnode*));

  myNode->word = (char*)malloc((strlen(word))*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(myNode->word,word);
  myNode->count = 1;
  myNode->line = line;
  myNode->next = NULL;
  return myNode;
}
void freeNode(struct lnode * myNode){
  //free(myNode->word);
  //myNode->word = NULL;
  free(myNode);
  myNode = NULL;
}
int main(){
  struct lnode *n = newNode("Test", 2);
  free(n);
  return 0;
}
```

Gives this error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./listTest: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x085d008 ***
```

Comment: `myNode->word = (char*)malloc((strlen(word))*sizeof(char));` make that `myNode->word = malloc(1+strlen(word));` (Or use `strdup()` ) And: your function `freeNode()` leaks memory. (again: the string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
  struct lnode *myNode = malloc(sizeof(struct  lnode*));
```

to

```
  struct lnode *myNode = malloc(sizeof(struct  lnode));
```

and

```
  myNode->word = (char*)malloc((strlen(word))*sizeof(char));
```

to

```
  myNode->word = (char*)malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Thank you for going through the effort to make the smallest test case you could.

Comment: good catch. This is why I prefer the idiom `struct lnode *myNode = malloc(sizeof *mynode);` Cannot go wrong.

Comment: Hmm, sizeof the pointer rather than sizeof the struct!  And then overwriting the malloc'd block's control data/ chain pointers by writing beyond the allocated block length.

Comment: Once you get used to it, it is easier, and less accident prone. `malloc (sizeof (typename))` is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @wildplasser, yeah, you are probably right. I deleted my comment already!

Comment: You must be a wizard or something... because I have made both of these changes before and they still resulted in the error, but now that I try it it works... Sorcery I say, anyway, thank you! Will accept this answer as soon as it lets me. :)

Comment: `strdup()` is still the preferred option IMHO, since it combines the `malloc(1+strlen(xxx))` and the `strcpy()` DRY!

Comment: @user1032369, you might have other similar errors in the code that you trimmed out to make the test case. Check that code carefully when you get back to it.

Comment: I agree with @wildplasser, use strdup() instead of malloc and strcpy.

Comment: All my test cases work now, and I can not find a single error in the code, and other people's test cases work just fine on my code, but her autograder keeps claiming there is a seg fault that simply isn't there. So I will probably just have to accept a 20% on the assignment. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: You don't have access to her test cases, right? They must be touching some part of the code that you haven't tested. Think about corner cases, null cases, things like that. Good luck.

Comment: No we dont have access to her test cases, but the problem isnt her test cases, the code doesnt even get to the cases because it thinks newNode doesnt work, but my code is nearly the same as everyone elses, my TA said it was correct, and my own test cases show that it runs fine. No clue whats going on, but thats just the way it is I guess, if you would like to look at the full code, here it is: http://pastebin.com/zXiurnPq